# How do I completely block the app store from an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore

I talked to customer service about this issue. The iMessage app contains access to the app store and it isn't something you can remove from the dock in there.

I need some ideas on how to block access to the app store as it has inappropriate content for my child, but they need to be able to use iMessage as well.

Restricting the app store app in screen time doesn't remove the widget from iMessage. It isn't able to be removed by conventional means, so looking for some suggestions.

Comment: If you use the iMessage widget with the restriction in place, are you able to actually view anything?

Comment: @Wowfunhappy yup, you can open the store and search through it as normal. The restrictions will not allow downloading apps but you can still browse the store which is an issue. Even with parental restrictions you can find apps like Playboy.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set "Screen Time Restrictions".

1. Go to settings
2. Select the "Screen Time" option
3. Select "Turn On Screen Time"
4. Select "This is my Child's Ipad"
5. Personalize
6. Select "Content and Privacy Restrictions" and turn it on
7. Select "Allowed Apps"
8. Disable App Store

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: As I mention in the post, restricting the app store in screentime doesn't remove it from the iMessage dock and it's still usable.

Comment: @kliuyyyy , what do you mean by iMessage dock? Is it the list of apps that appear on top of the keyboard?

Comment: Yep that's what I'm talking about. Unfortunately can't remove the app store widget from there